# Is there best practice for storing feature maps of images

Tags: python, database, machine-learning, image-processing

So I'm building an image search engine where a user can upload an image (query image) , and find other images stored in a directory ( target images) that have the query image in it.

Thats being done using SIFT by extracting the feature maps from both the query and source images and matching them.
Now to make this a feasible application, we'll need to store the feature maps somewhere so that when an image is queried we dont re-extract the feature maps of all images

The problem is that each feature map is around 2k rows with 128 columns per image, totalling about 6mb of storage.
For 1,000,000 image, that would be around 6TB of storage, i dont think this would be scalable and would fit in a database engine properly.

I'm kinda lost from here, how should i store and retrieve such feature maps

Your help is much appreciated!

Edit: the target images are always evolving and not just a static dataset